# War Card Game Shuffle Function Returning Negative #'s

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>  
#include <algorithm> 
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

//Class for a card deck:
class CardDeck
{
public:
CardDeck(int theValue, string theSuit);
CardDeck(){} 

// Setters--Don't think we will need
void setValue(int theValue);
void setSuit(string theSuit);

// Getters
int getValue();
string getSuit();
private:
int value;
string suit; 
};// end CardDeck class



int main()
{
int i = 0; 
int gameInPlay = 1;

const string DR = "Dragons";
const string MG = "Mages";
const string WR = "Warriors";
const string CF = "Confessors";


vector<CardDeck> startDeck(52);
vector<CardDeck> tempCards(1); 

// Dragons Suit
for (i = 0; i < 13; i++)
{
    startDeck[i].setValue(i - 12);
    startDeck[i].setSuit("Dragons");
    //startDeck[i].setValue(i+1);
    //  startDeck[i].setSuit("Dragons");
}
// Mages Suit
for (i = 13; i < 26; i++)
{
    startDeck[i].setValue(i - 12);
    startDeck[i].setSuit("Mages");
}
for (i = 26; i < 39; i++)
{
    startDeck[i].setValue(i - 25);
    startDeck[i].setSuit("Warriors");
}

for (i = 39; i < 52; i++)
{
    startDeck[i].setValue(i - 38);
    startDeck[i].setSuit("Confessors");
}


// Output for de-bug
cout << "The first card is " << startDeck[0].getValue() << " of " << startDeck[0].getSuit() << endl;
cout << "The second card is " << startDeck[1].getValue() << " of " << startDeck[1].getSuit() << "\n\n";



//****************************************************************************
// Shuffle the deck
int shuffleTimes = (rand() % 120) + 1;
// Need to shuffle a random # of times, else deck is
// "shuffled" in same order every time
for (int i = 0; i < shuffleTimes; i++)
{
    srand(time(0));
    for (i = 0; i < startDeck.size(); i++)
    {
        int second = rand() % startDeck.size();
        CardDeck temp = startDeck[i];
        startDeck[i] = startDeck[second];
        startDeck[second] = temp;

    }
}
//*******************************************************************************



// Verify cards are shuffled for de-bug
cout << "After shuffling:\n Value \t Suit\n";

// Output for de-bug
cout << "The first card is " << startDeck[0].getValue() << " of " << startDeck[0].getSuit() << endl;
cout << "The second card is " << startDeck[1].getValue() << " of " << startDeck[1].getSuit() << endl;


// Creat human deck
vector<CardDeck> humanDeck(26);
for (i = 0; i< 26; i++)
{
    humanDeck[i] = startDeck[i];

}

// Creat computer deck
vector<CardDeck> computerDeck(26);
for (i = 0; i< 26; i++)
{
    computerDeck[i] = startDeck[i + 26];

}


// Output for de-bug
cout << "The first human card is " << humanDeck[0].getValue() << " of " << humanDeck[0].getSuit() << endl;
cout << "The second human card is " << humanDeck[1].getValue() << " of " << humanDeck[1].getSuit() << "\n\n";

cout << "The first computer card is " << computerDeck[0].getValue() << " of " << computerDeck[0].getSuit() << endl;
cout << "The second computer card is " << computerDeck[1].getValue() << " of " << computerDeck[1].getSuit() << "\n\n";



getchar();
return 0;

} // end main

// Functions for CardDeck class
CardDeck::CardDeck(int theValue, string theSuit)
{
value = theValue;
suit = theSuit;
}

void CardDeck::setValue(int theValue)
{
value = theValue;
}

void CardDeck::setSuit(string theSuit)
{
suit = theSuit;
}

int CardDeck::getValue()
{
return value;
}

string CardDeck::getSuit()
{
return suit;
}
```

Obviously not done with the game, and I am new to C++ and programming so any help will do

I would like some help trying to figure out how to get only positive numbers instead of negative. Also would like to figure out why they return values of the first two outputs are always the same.

- Thank you

Comment: If `i` is `0` and you do `i - 12` what's the result?

Comment: BTW `srand()` should be called at the very beginning of the program and never again

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant to do this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 13; i++)
{
    startDeck[i].setValue(i+1);
    startDeck[i].setSuit("Dragons");
    //startDeck[i].setValue(i+1);
    //  startDeck[i].setSuit("Dragons");
}
```

Otherwise, `startDeck[i].setValue(i-12);` will set negative values for i < 12, which is most of that loop.

I'm wondering why you have the correct code there and commented out...what was the issue with it?

Comment: Working with others, and since I had an account on here, I just copy pasted. Thank you